# pythonic module organization - how to refer to files in root directory?

Tags: python, unix, module, pythonpath

I have my python code in a folder called "project", so my code files are in project/*.py.  I want to have submodules within it, e.g.

```
project/code.py # where code lives
project/mymodule1  # where more code lives
project/mymodule2
```

each module directory has its own **init**.py file, e.g.

```
project/mymodule1/__init__.py
```

suppose I have a file "test.py" within mymodule1 (project/mymodule1/test.py) and I'd like to refer to something from "code", e.g. import the function "myfunc"

```
== project/mymodule1/test.py ==
from code import myfunc
```

the problem is that "code" will not be found unless the user has placed the "project/" directory in their PYTHONPATH. Is there a way to avoid this and use some kind of "relative path" to import myfunc, e.g.

```
from ../code import myfunc
```

basically, I don't want to force users of the code to alter the PYTHONPATH unless I can do it programmatically for them from within my script.  I'd like it to work out of the box.

How can this be done? either solution is good: altering PYTHONPATH programmatically, or more ideally, refering to "code" using some kind of relative importing, since even though I don't know where "project/code.py" lives on the user's computer, I know where it is relative to "myfunc".

EDIT: Can someone please show proper example of intra-package import? I tried, from "mymodule1" to do:

```
from .. import foo
```

where "foo" is in code.py but it does not work. I have **init**.py in mymodule1, so:

```
project/code.py
project/mymodule1/__init__.py
project/mymodule1/module1_code.py
```

where module1_code.py tries to import foo, a function defined in "code.py".

EDIT: The main confusion I still have is that even after adopting the example given in response to my message, showing the project/sub1/test hierarchy, you still cannot "cd" into sub1 and do "python test.py" and have it work. The user has to be in the directory containing "project" and do "import project.sub1.test".  I'd like this to work regardless of what directory the user is in.  The user in this case has to execute the file "test.py", which lives in project/sub1/.  So the test case is:

```
$ cd project/sub1
$ python test.py
```

which yields the error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

how can this be fixed?

thanks.

Comment: Is `code.py` also importing `mymodule1/test.py`? If so, you're going to want to look at reorganizing your code. Circular imports should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in Python 2.5 and above.  See the docs on [Intra-Package References](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

A couple of things to note:

If you intend for your users to *install* your package somewhere, for example using distutils or setuptools, then `project` will likely already be in the search path, and you can change the relative import to `from project.code import ...` or similar.

In the case where your users are installing your package to a non-standard directory (e.g. their home directory, someplace else that's not in `sys.path`, etc.), my opinion is that it leads to less confusion to instruct the user to modify `PYTHONPATH` rather than programmatically change `sys.path`.

In the case where you don't intend your users to install your code at all - for example, they will simply be untarring the source, cd'ing to the parent directory of `project`, and running a script - then intra-package references and relative imports will probably work fine.

**EDIT**: per request, here's an example:

Suppose package layout is as follows:

```
project/
    __init__.py (empty)
    code.py
    sub1/
        __init__.py (empty)
        test.py
```

Now, the contents of `project/code.py` are:

```
# code.py (module that resides in main "project" package)

def foo():
    print "this is code.foo"
```

And, the contents of `project/sub1/test.py` are:

```
# test.py (module that resides in "sub1" subpackage of main "project" package)

from ..code import foo
foo()
```

So, `test.py` imports the name `foo` from the relative path `..code`, which uses intra-package references to get us back to the `code.py` module within the *parent* (that's the `..` part) of the `sub1.test` package where we are executing from.

To test this:

```
shell$ (cd to directory where "project" package is located)
shell$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Aug  2 2010, 20:10:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import project.sub1.test
this is code.foo
```

Note that the double dot in the `from .. import X` syntax merely gets you to the parent package, but you can specify modules within that package.

In other words, `from .. import X` in this case is equivalent to `from project import X`, and thus `X` must either be a module in `project` or a class/function/name within `project/__init__.py`.

Thus, `from ..code import X` is equivalent to `from project.code import X`.

Comment: Can someone please show proper example of intra-package import? I tried, from "mymodule1" to do: from .. import foo, where "foo" is in code.py but it does not work. I have __init__.py in mymodule1

Comment: @user248237: see my amended response including an example.  The main difference is that `from .. import foo` is equivalent to searching `project/__init__.py`, not `code.py`.

Comment: what I don't get is why if you cd into "sub1" and do: python test.py, you get the error "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

Answer (score 1):

best way to avoid this is to keep all your code in a `src` folder or better name it on your project e.g. `myproject` and keep a `__init__.py` there, so you can do this

```
from myproject import code
```

so your folder structure would be

```
project
    main.py
    myproject
        __init__.py
        code.py
        module1
        module2
```

`main.py` or whatever name you give it should not have much code, it should get required module from `myproject` and run it e.g.

```
from myproject import myapp
myapp.run()
```

see a good [article](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html) on how to arrange your python project.

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem -- how can module1's code call things defined upstream? in parent dirs?

Comment: myproject will be in python path and everymodule can import any module e.g. `from myproject.module1 import xxx`

Comment: 1) I think you mean 'project' will be in PYTHONPATH, not 'myproject', and (2) No it won't if process was started using 'python myproject/code.py", which is the OP's situation. His question is still unresolved, IMHO.

Comment: @JonathanHartley I was giving a alternate and better organization which helps in future also when he want to pack myproject as a library or run it as a standalone app, main entry point is main.py in my solution not code.py

Comment: @AnuragUniyal Understood, thanks. In general I totally agree with your approach. However, I'm doubtful about it today, because I have inherited a project which contains many dozens of command-line scripts, not just a single "main.py". The original author chose to categorise these into several project subdirectories, rather than put them all in the project top level directory. Unfortunately, they all therefore mangle sys.path in order to be able to import. Is moving them *all* to the project TLD my only alternative? I think I'd almost rather limp along with path mangling. Advice welcome.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal oh, and my point (1) above still stands. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @JonathanHartley there could be many ways to do this, path mangling is one but I will presonally prefer only two approches a) either make each project a proper module under my project or b) if all projects are too disjoint and developed separately I will just make them a library and install them like any other python library

Comment: When you say "make each project a proper module under my project", what do you mean? I only have one project. It contains many executable scripts.